# в build.gradle подчеркивает красным цветом библиотеки

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

[image]
На что может повлиять данная ошибка (Если это конечно ошибка) ?
И как исправить красное подчеркивание? На какую версию поменять ?

```
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 20
    versionName "1.2.8"

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.16'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'org.ini4j:ini4j:0.5.4'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'org.quuux.feller:feller:0.1'
compile 'org.quuux.sack:sack:0.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
// Google Services
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:10.2.1'
// Firebase Google
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.0'
//Library for Chat
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
//Library for NavigationDrawer
compile('com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:2.9.2@aar')
compile 'com.mikepenz.iconics:library:0.9.1@aar'
compile 'com.github.wrdlbrnft:sorted-list-adapter:0.2.0.19'
compile 'com.github.claucookie.miniequalizer:library:1.0.0'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если навести курсор на ошибку, то студия вам напишет `This support library should not use a different version (23) than the compileSdkVersion()`, это значит, что вы не должны использовать версию библиотеки поддержки, отличную от `compileSdkVersion`.

Comment: какую версию библиотек использовать тогда, если targetSdkVersion 25 ?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25

Comment: @Антон 25.3.1     .

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка исчезла!)